# Putting output of 'git describe' in template using play framework?

Tags: git, playframework

I'd like to show the output of 'git describe' in my view. Do I need to write a plug-in that updates a value and sets it application wide? Or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just read about play modules and decided to write one (https://github.com/killdashnine/play-git-plugin) to see if I could solve my problem:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import play.Logger;
import play.Play;
import play.PlayPlugin;

public class GitPlugin extends PlayPlugin {

        private static String GIT_PLUGIN_PREFIX = "GIT plugin: ";

        @Override
        public void onApplicationStart()  {
                Logger.info(GIT_PLUGIN_PREFIX + "executing 'git describe'");
                final StringBuffer gitVersion = new StringBuffer();
                try {
                        final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("git describe"); 
                        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); 

                        // wait for process to complete
                        p.waitFor(); 

                        // read the output
                        String line = reader.readLine(); 
                        while(line != null) { 
                                gitVersion.append(line); 
                                line = reader.readLine(); 
                        } 
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                        Logger.error(GIT_PLUGIN_PREFIX + "unable to execute 'git describe'");
                }

                // set a property for this value
                Play.configuration.setProperty("git.revision", gitVersion.toString());

                Logger.info(GIT_PLUGIN_PREFIX + "revision is " + gitVersion.toString());
        }
}
```

Which results in:

```
12:14:46,508 INFO  ~ GIT plugin: executing 'git describe'
12:14:46,513 INFO  ~ GIT plugin: revision is V0-beta-7-gac9af80
```

In my controller:

```
    @Before
    static void addDefaults() {
        renderArgs.put("version", Play.configuration.getProperty("git.revision"));
     }
```

Of course this is not very portable and could be improved. Possible improvement would be to allow a custom command to be run via a settings in your configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't run your code from a git repo you could do like me, i have a build script that produces a war file and in this script i'll do:

```
cat > {apppath}/conf/application_version.properties << EOF
application.version=`git describe`
application.buildtime=`date`
EOF
...
```

And in @OnApplicationStart class i add the properties

```
private def readApplicationVersion() {
    Logger.info("Bootstrap.readApplicationVersion file")
    Play.id match {
        case "" | "test" => Play.configuration.put("application.version", "TEST-MODE");  Play.configuration.put("application.buildtime", "YEAH BABY YEAH REALTIME")
        case _ => addFileProp(VirtualFile.open(Play.applicationPath).child("conf/application_version.properties").inputstream())
    }
}

private def addFileProp(input: InputStream) {
    input match {
        case null => Logger.error("can't find config file, Play id: " + Play.id + ". Will exit now.")
        case _ => val extendCconfiguration = IO.readUtf8Properties(input);
        for (key <- extendCconfiguration.keys) {
            Play.configuration.put(key, extendCconfiguration.get(key))
        }
    }
}
```

And from the Controller

```
object ApplicationVersion extends Controller {
    def version = {
        Json("{iamVersion: '"+configuration.getProperty("application.version")+"', buildTime: '"+configuration.getProperty("application.buildtime")+"'}")
    }
}
```