# Git: Need cross-branch version number

Tags: git, version, git-branch

I would like to generate a simple, increasing version integer,
based on when a commit has changed a certain folder. And, I want
this version number to be valid across branches.

To illustrate, suppose the folder is named FOO, and it is on BRANCH1 and BRANCH2.
Let's say version V is currently equal to 10.

1) make a commit that modifies FOO on BRANCH1:  I would like V = 11
2) now make a commit that modifies FOO on BRANCH2: I would like V = 12

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Jacko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Branches are mere pointers on a graph.

[`git describe`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-describe.html) remains the only "label" valid across repos.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337880/putting-output-of-git-describe-in-template-using-play-framework) has an example where git describe is used to generate a "Vxxx".

You also have [`git name-rev`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917102/in-git-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-friendly-name-for-an-arbitrary-commit) if you want a "label" relative to a branch (but not valid across repos).